# Blender - black mesh is displayed in render view, but in material view it looks fine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, 3d-view, shaders, error

I'm working on a project, and today I got stuck on this.
I'm using the "experimental Cycles" rendering engine.

This is how the setup looks in material preview mode:
[image]

And, this is how the render view is displaying my scene:
[image]
*As you can see, the other textures work properly.*

Now, after reading some threads on here I saw someone suggest replacing the material.
I did that, and the result was the same.

**What I've checked:**

1. face orientation is done properly.
2. I applied the scale and rotation.
3. No duplicate vertices.
4. Unwrapped the UV.
5. The material works on a simple plain.
6. Added a new light, still the same.
7. I recalculated the normals.

I think ( not an expert, just a thought ) that I might've screwed up somewhere in the mesh. It is pretty ugly when you go into edit mode :)

[image]

If any **additional info** is needed, let me know.
And **Thank you for your time** reading this :)

Comment: Have you used special options, like shadow terminator?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I didn't use anything special. I tried using shadow catcher, but I think I reverted correctly the changes I made. Also, I added a link with the blend file. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is set as shadow catcher.

Uncheck this option :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. :)